# Unable to end this dice game properly

Tags: java, dice

I am trying to end this game properly but the do while loop or something I am doing is causing the game to keep going. If someone has further advice for me to end this game after either score reaches 99 I would appreciate it. I have pasted both classes sources. I am also student so do forgive me.

class

```
package programming2;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matador {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        /*The game is played between the player and the computer.
        The player's score and the computer's score each begin at 0.
        The object of the game is to be the first reach 99 points.
        The player and the computer take turns. On each turn: */
        
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);  
        Die matador = new Die();
        
        int playerScore = 0;
        int computerScore = 0;
        int playerPick = 0;
        int cpu;
        int turn;
        
        Random randGen = new Random();
        cpu = randGen.nextInt(6) + 2; 
        int cpuPick = 0;
        int quit = 0;
        
        System.out.println("Welcome to el Matador!");
        System.out.println("The winner of this game is the first to score 99 points");
        
        do {System.out.println("Player 1 please pick your number");  // start of master loop
        
        playerPick = scnr.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Player 1 you selected " + playerPick);
        
        System.out.println("Player 2 please pick your number");
        
        cpuPick = cpu;
        
        System.out.println("Player 2 selects " + cpuPick);
        
        
           // 
        do {    // start of game loop - master do loop player 1
            
            if (computerScore > 98) {
                
                quit = 1;
                break;
            }
            
            System.out.println("Player 1 rolls dice");
            
            matador.rollDieNow();
            
            System.out.println("Values for 1st dice is: " + matador.getValueDie1() + " and " + matador.getValueDie2());
            System.out.println("Combined values are " + matador.getValue());
            
            turn = 0;       // start of loop marker for player 1 
            
            
            
            if (matador.getValueDie1() == 1 && matador.getValueDie2() == 1) {
        
            
            playerScore = playerScore + -25;
            break;
            
            }
            
            
        
        if (matador.getValueDie1() == 1 || matador.getValueDie2() == 1) {
            
            playerScore = playerScore + 0;
            System.out.println("Changing Turns!");
            break;
            
        }
        
        if (matador.getValueDie1() != 1 || matador.getValueDie2() != 1) {     // sum of dicevalue added to score 
            
            playerScore = playerScore + matador.getValue();
           
           
           }
        
        if (playerPick == matador.getValueDie1() || playerPick == matador.getValueDie2()) {  // if picked number appears on at least 1 
            
            turn = turn + 1;
        }
        
        if (playerPick == matador.getValueDie1() && playerPick == matador.getValueDie2()) {   // if picked number appears on both dice
            
            System.out.println("You are the winner player 1 you matched your numbers!!");
            System.out.print("Player 1 final score is: " + playerScore + " |-| player 2 final score is " + computerScore);
            quit = 1;
            break;
            
            
        }
        
       
            
            System.out.println("Player 1 Score: " + playerScore);
        
        
        }
    
        while (turn < turn + 1 || quit != 1);
        
        // turn changes and also end of loop marker 
        System.out.println("Score update! Player 1 score is: " + playerScore + " |-| player 2 score is " + computerScore);
        
        turn = 0;     // turn counter resets 

        do {       // start of computer player's turn 
            
            if (playerScore > 98) {
                
            quit = 1;
            break;
            
            }
            
            System.out.println("Player 2 rolls dice");
            matador.rollDieNow();
            System.out.println("Values for 1st dice is: " + matador.getValueDie1() + " and " + matador.getValueDie2());
            System.out.println("Combined values are " + matador.getValue());
            
            
            
            if (matador.getValueDie1() == 1 && matador.getValueDie2() == 1) {    // loop marker for cpu starts 
    
        
        computerScore = computerScore + -25;   
        
    
        break;
        
        }
        

    
    if (matador.getValueDie1() == 1 && matador.getValueDie2() == 1) {      // loses turns if 1 appears on both sides
        
        computerScore = computerScore + 0;
        System.out.println("Changing Turns!");
        break;
        
    }
    
    if (matador.getValueDie1() != 1 || matador.getValueDie2() != 1) {  // computer scores  value of dice 
        
        computerScore = computerScore + matador.getValue();
        
        if (computerScore > 98) {
    
        break; 
        
        }
        
    }
    
    if (cpuPick == matador.getValueDie1() || cpuPick == matador.getValueDie2()) {
        
        turn = turn + 1;
    }
    
    if (cpuPick == matador.getValueDie1() && cpuPick == matador.getValueDie2()) {
        
        System.out.println("You are the winner player 2 you matched your numbers!!");
        System.out.println("Player 1 final score is: " + playerScore + " |-| player 2 final score is " + computerScore);
        quit = 1;
        break;
    }
        
    
    System.out.println("Player 2 Score: " + computerScore);
    
    
        }   

        
        
    while (playerScore < 98 || computerScore <98 || quit != 1);   
        
        
        
        }
        
        while (playerScore < 98 || computerScore < 98 || quit != 1);    // end of master loop 
        System.out.println("Player 1 final score is: " + playerScore + " |-| player 2 final score is " + computerScore);
        

        
        

    }

}
```

other class if needed but it has nothing to do with the score as its mainly for determining some values:

```
package programming2;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Die {   
    
    private int die1;   //instance variable 
    private int die2;
    private int rolledDice;
    
    
    public Die() {                //constructor assigns random value
        
        
        
        die1 = (int) (Math.random()*6)+1;   
        die2 = (int) (Math.random()*6)+1;
          
                
    }
    
    public void rollDieNow () {                     //rolls dice 
        
        
        Random randGen = new Random();
        
        
        
        die1 = randGen.nextInt(6) + 1; 
        die2 = randGen.nextInt(6) + 1; 
           
       }
    
     
    public int getValue() {       // gets dice value 
    
    
        
    rolledDice = die1 + die2;
    
        
    return rolledDice;
    
    }
    
    public int getValueDie1() {       // gets die1 value 
        
        
        
        
        
            
        return die1;
        
        }
    
    public int getValueDie2() {       // gets die2 value 
        
        
        
        
        
            
        return die2;
        
        }

    

}
```

Comment: What does this condition mean : `turn < turn + 1`  ?

Comment: `while (playerScore < 98 || computerScore < 98 || quit != 1)` <- Those `||` should probably be `&&`. You want to run your loop(s) as long as all those conditions are fulfilled, not as long as at least one of them is fullfilled. Currently your loop will only stop when `playerScore >= 98` and `computerScore >=98` and `quit==1`. But just reaching one of those conditions should mark the end of the game.

Comment: im using the variable turn to determine when the players turn is over, as you can see the if conditions. Turn increases in some conditions turn is lost so I use break to break the loop and allow the other player to choose.

Answer (score -1):

dice class

```
package finalproject2;

import java.util.Random;

public class Die {

    Random randGen = new Random();
    private int value; // instance variable -> stores the roll
    // each Die object gets its own copy of the instance variable
    
    public Die() { // constructor rolls dice (calls rollDieNow() method)
        rollDieNow();
    }

    public void rollDieNow() { // rolls dice
        value = randGen.nextInt(6) + 1;
    }

    public int getValue() { // gets dice value
        return value;
    }

}
```

Matador Class

```
package finalproject2;


import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matador {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        /*The game is played between the player and the computer.
        The player's score and the computer's score each begin at 0.
        The object of the game is to be the first reach 99 points.
        The player and the computer take turns. On each turn: */
        
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);  
        
        Die d1 = new Die();
        Die d2 = new Die();
        
        
        
        int playerScore = 0;
        int computerScore = 0;
        int playerPick = 0;
        int cpu;
        int turn;
        int sum ;
        
        Random randGen = new Random();
        cpu = randGen.nextInt(6) + 2; 
        int cpuPick = 0;
        int quit = 0;
        
        System.out.println("Welcome to el Matador!");
        System.out.println("The winner of this game is the first to score 99 points");
        
        // use System.exit(0) to stop program execution
        
        do {
            
            if (playerScore >= 99 || computerScore >= 99) {
                
            System.out.println("Game Over!");
            System.exit(0);
            }
            
            System.out.println("Player 1 please pick your number");  // start of master loop
        
        playerPick = scnr.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Player 1 you selected " + playerPick);
        
        System.out.println("Player 2 please pick your number");
        
        cpuPick = cpu;
        
        System.out.println("Player 2 selects " + cpuPick);
        
        
           // 
        do {    // start of game loop - master do loop player 1
            
        
            System.out.println("Player 1 rolls dice");
            
            d1.rollDieNow();
            d2.rollDieNow();
            sum = d1.getValue() + d2.getValue() ;
            
            System.out.println("Values for both dice are: " + d1.getValue() + " and " + d2.getValue());
            System.out.println("Combined values are " + sum);
            
            turn = 0;       // start of loop marker for player 1 
            
            
            
            if (d1.getValue() == 1 && d2.getValue() == 1) {
        
            
            playerScore = playerScore + -25;
            System.out.println("Ouch! Lost 25 points!");

            break;  // lost of turn, loop ends 
            
            }
            
            
        
        if (d1.getValue() == 1 || d2.getValue() == 1) {
            
            playerScore = playerScore + 0;
            System.out.println("Changing Turns!");
            break; // lost of turn loop ends
            
        }
        
        if (d1.getValue() != 1 || d2.getValue() != 1) {     // sum of dice value added to score 
            
            playerScore = playerScore + (d1.getValue() + d2.getValue());
            System.out.println("Gained points! " + (d1.getValue() + d2.getValue()));

           
           
           }
        
        if (playerPick == d1.getValue() || playerPick == d2.getValue()) {  // if picked number appears on at least 1 
            
            turn = turn + 1;
        }
        
        if (playerPick == d1.getValue() && playerPick == d2.getValue()) {   // if picked number appears on both dice
            
            System.out.println("You are the winner player 1 you matched your numbers!!");
            System.out.print("Player 1 final score is: " + playerScore + " |-| player 2 final score is " + computerScore);
            System.exit(0); // game ends completely
            
            
        }
        
       
            
            System.out.println("Player 1 Score: " + playerScore);
        
        
        }
    
        while (turn < 1);
        
        // turn changes and also end of loop marker 
        System.out.println("Score update! Player 1 score is: " + playerScore + " |-| player 2 score is " + computerScore);
        
        turn = 0;     // turn counter resets 

        do {       // start of computer player's turn 
            
            if (playerScore >= 99 || computerScore >= 99) {
                
                System.out.println("Game Over!");
                System.exit(0);
                }
            
            System.out.println("Player 2 rolls dice");
            d1.rollDieNow();
            d2.rollDieNow();
            System.out.println("Values for 1st dice is: " + d1.getValue() + " and " + d2.getValue());
            System.out.println("Combined values are " + (d1.getValue() + d2.getValue()));
            
            
            
            
            if (d1.getValue() == 1 && d2.getValue() == 1) {    // loses points and turn  
    
        
        computerScore = computerScore + -25; 
        System.out.println("Ouch! Lost 25 points!");
        
    
        break;
        
        }
        

    
    if (d1.getValue() == 1 || d2.getValue() == 1) {      // loses turns if 1 appears on both sides
        
        computerScore = computerScore + 0;
        System.out.println("Changing Turns!");
        break;
        
    }
    
    if (d1.getValue() != 1 || d2.getValue() != 1) {  // computer scores  value of dice 
        
        computerScore = computerScore + (d1.getValue() + d2.getValue());
        
        System.out.println("Gained points! " + (d1.getValue() + d2.getValue()));
        
        }
        
    
    
    if (cpuPick == d1.getValue() || cpuPick == d2.getValue()) {
        
        turn = turn + 1;
    }
    
    if (cpuPick == d1.getValue() && cpuPick == d2.getValue()) {
        
        System.out.println("You are the winner player 2 you matched your numbers!!");
        System.out.println("Player 1 final score is: " + playerScore + " |-| player 2 final score is " + computerScore);
        System.exit(0);
    }
        
    
    System.out.println("Player 2 Score: " + computerScore);
    
    
        }   

        
        
    while (turn < 1);   // for some reason on my previous revision this was set to 
                        // a different condition than player 1, now the game ends appropiate
        
        
        
        }
        
        while (playerScore <= 99 || computerScore <= 99);    // end of master loop 
        System.out.println("Player 1 final score is: " + playerScore + " |-| player 2 final score is " + computerScore);
        

        
        

    }

}
```

Comment: Dumping code into a post isn't really an answer. What are you doing? What was wrong with the original? How does your code address that problem?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).